# How to add Image and title to the Notification music control from react-native-video

Tags: notifications, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-video

I am using [react-native-video](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video), When I play video from any resource(url or local both) then in notification center music control show. But there is nothing information show in the notification. How can I add Image and title into the notification center [iOS].

My code look like this :-

```
<Video
  key={song.id}
  source={{ uri: song.url }}
  ref={videoPlayer}
  paused={IsPlaying}
  playInBackground={true}
  hideShutterView={true}
  resizeMode={"cover"}
  controls
  onEnd={() => {
    newProcess();
  }}
  poster={Thumbnail}
  ignoreSilentSwitch={"ignore"}
  style={styles.backgroundVideo}
  fullscreenAutorotate={"landscape"}
  fullscreenOrientation={"landscape"}
  onFullScreen={true}
/>;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @Pankaj we decited to switch to Kotlin as React Native is not that good for big apps